# Reduce size of WSUS offline updater

Tags: windows-7, windows, wsus

I need to get the size of wsus_client folder to under 2GB. Im only generating updates for Windows 7 and MS office.

I compared the newest generated offline updates with the one I created the last time my systems were updated and removed everything but the latest .exe and .cab files in the windows 7 folder "wsus_client\w61\glb". However, WSUS hangs on "Listing missing updates...."